# openssl make test error, can install?

Tags: openssl

i will upgrade opessl on ubuntu 14.04, config and make are succees, but run make test is fail, can install continue?
the make test error log:

```
../test/recipes/05-test_md2.t .............. skipped: md2 is not supported by this OpenSSL build
../test/recipes/05-test_rc5.t .............. skipped: rc5 is not supported by this OpenSSL build
../test/recipes/30-test_afalg.t ............ skipped: test_afalg not supported for this build
../test/recipes/40-test_rehash.t ........... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/5 subtests 
        (less 1 skipped subtest: 3 okay)
../test/recipes/90-test_heartbeat.t ........ skipped: heartbeats is not supported by this OpenSSL build
Test Summary Report
-------------------
../test/recipes/40-test_rehash.t         (Wstat: 256 Tests: 5 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  4
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=95, Tests=547, 53 wallclock secs ( 0.31 usr  0.10 sys + 40.48 cusr  1.90 csys = 42.79 CPU)
Result: FAIL
make[1]: *** [_tests] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/openssl-1.1.0f'
make: *** [tests] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ../test/recipes/40-test_rehash.t ........... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
> ```
>
> Failed 1/5 subtests

I believe this happens under OpenSSL 1.0.2 if either (1) you run the self tests as root; to (2) you fail to run the self tests as root. I think its the former one (1). You can ignore this one if you want.

You should build the library and run the self tests as a regular user. Use `sudo` when it comes time to install.